# AWK - replace columns between them

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to replace the 1st column of the file with the last one. So for this file:

```
A B C D E F
```

the result would be:

```
F B C D E A
```

I've tried to do so:

```
awk '{$a = $1; $1 = $NF; $NF = $a; print }' myfile > secfile
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Try `a` instead of `$a`.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, since the OP knows how to do this. It is just that he missed what was the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

As Wintermute says in comments, you have to use `a` instead of `$a`:

```
awk '{a = $1; $1 = $NF; $NF = a; print }' myfile > secfile
      ^
      no $a !
```

This is because variables in `awk` do not have leading `$`. The `$x` syntax is used to call the fields in the record, so that `$x` stands for the field on the position stored in the variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use sed.

```
sed 's/^\([^\s]*\)\(.*\s\)\([^\s]*\)$/\3\2\1/' file
```